# render dynamic content into inherited blazor layout

Tags: inheritance, layout, nested, blazor

I am trying to create a blazor page that has a main layout and various inherited layouts for different areas. I want to have a second set of menu options rendered in the head which is in the main layout. I have tried to do this with renderfragments, but I cant get it to work and the examples are all based around rendering the content in a child component using a parameter. Is this possible? If not is there another way to do this?

At the moment I have a MainLayout which has a top level nav menu in the header and renders the body in a bootstrap container.

I then have a second layout that inherits the main layout. here i would like to have an additional nav with content specific links. The problem is that the nav menu is inside a header, and i want the body rendered inside a bootstrap container.

[here is a link to a blazor fiddle that shows the structure](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/p6jb6cj0)

Is this possible? Effectively i want to render a section like in razor. Also I have not found a good way to setup areas like in MVC and cant find any good resources to show how this can be done. If anybody knows this I would also be very grateful for some links or insight.

Thanks